# How to sort the antd-table while keep one special line forever on the top of the table?

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

I'm using react and ant design 3.26 to build my website, and using the antd_table to show some data.Now I need to sort the table while keep one speical row on the top of the table forever and dont be influenced by the sorter(neither descend nor ascend).Do I have some easy way to make this effect？

I dont want to use `onChange()` to do some complex function to manage the datasource and the state，just want to use the default sorter props provided by antd-table。

Here is a simple demo:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table} from "antd";

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    shouldForeverTop: true,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    shouldForeverTop: false,
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    shouldForeverTop: false,
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
    shouldForeverTop: false,
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length,
      },
      {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
      },
      {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
      },
    ];
    return (
        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data}/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the first line data to the a or b, If the `a.name === data[0].name` then `return 0`

```
 sorter: (a, b) => {
   if(a.name === data[0].name || b.name === data[0].name) return 0;
   return a.name.length - b.name.length
 },
```

Comment: thanks beyond words.This answer is so useful and elegant, and let me know how `sorter()`  sort the array, thanks again.

Comment: Now how would you do it the opposite? so that it is always last, not first? I want `null` values to always be last, but I just can't get it to stick there without flipping on `desc` to `asc` sorting...

Answer (score 0):

For how sorter() works: a and b are the values or in your case the names to be considered. At the start, a will be the first name in the column and b the second, then it will move further down the column. Well, the sorter actually returns either true or false. So, lets suppose the first name in the column is jim and the second is john. Now when a.name.length (which is 3) - b.name.length (which is 4), 3 - 4 returns false (because it's -1), so the names will not be interchanged and jim will stay on top of john. Now moving further down the column, john will become a and the next name let's say tim, will become b, and again comparison will be done between these two. If sorter returns true (in this john and tim case it will return true), then interchange will happen. Hope it was very clear.